# BIRT report parameter multiple selection value "All"

Tags: eclipse, parameters, birt

I have a problem with creating default value of 'All values' for a cascading parameter group last parameter. Actually I don't neccesary need that value to be default, but that would be preferable.

I have tried where I create additional data set with the needed value and additional data set with value All which uses different scripted data source, and another data set with computed column with full outer join, that column uses this code

```
if(row["userName"]==null ){
row["All"];
}else{
row["userName"];
}
```

and in the last cascaded parameter JDSuser which I need that All value I have added default value (All users).

In the data set with one value All in open I have script

```
ii=0;
```

in fetch

```
if( ii > 0 ){
return false;
}else{
row["All"] = "(All Users)";
ii++
return true;
}
```

and in the query data set, in beforeOpen script in if statement I have

```
if( params["JDSuser"].value!=null && params["JDSuser"].value[0] != "(All Users)" ){
```

This is used if I haven't selected All users value, and this works, though if I select All Users, it retrieves me no data.

I'm creating from this source example [actuate link for example rptdesign download](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/593-default-value-all-with-multi-select-parsmeter/)

If someone could give me some help, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The way you generate "(All values)" item in your selection list seems to me over complicated but if i understood correctly your case this part is working fine, the problem is not in the definition of the cascading parameter but the way it is used in the main dataset of the report.

Furthermore we have to assume we speak about the same query & beforeOpen script involved in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745709/multiple-parameter-values). No data are returned because if we don't do anything special when this item "All values" has been selected, then those filters are still active:

```
and role.name in ( 'sample grupa' )
and userbase.userName in ( 'sample' )
```

There are a couple of options to handle this. An elegant one is to declare a **dataset parameter** linked to your report parameter "JDSuser", and use a clause "OR" such:

```
and role.name in ( 'sample grupa' )
and (?='(All users)' OR userbase.userName in ( 'sample' ))
```

Notice this question mark, which represents a dataset parameter in your query. It is not intrusive: the beforeOpen script doesn't have to be changed. You probably need to do something similar with the other filter role.name, but you don't provide any information related to this. One more thing, in order to avoid bad surpises may be you should choose as value something more simple without brackets such "_allitems", and set  "(All items)" as label.

Please refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073182/if-else-alternative-for-multiple-sql-criteria-for-use-in-birt/21077675#21077675) for more informations about handling optional parameters. See a live example of optional parameters in a cascading group [here](http://www.visioneo.org/cascading-parameters).